# SemanticException Can not find <TABLE-NAME> in genColumnStatsTask (state=42000,code=40000)

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm getting the exception for SQL query on the hive

```
create table temp as 
select t.type
from temp1 LATERAL VIEW posexplode(c1.array_of_struct_field1) dummy as alias1, t
union all
select t.type
from temp1 LATERAL VIEW posexplode(c1.array_of_struct_field2) dummy as alias1, t;
```

Below I'm adding the exception for the query.

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Can
> not find database1.temp in genColumnStatsTask
> (state=42000,code=40000)

Answer (score 0):

Use the union all query as below way.

```
create table temp as 
select t.type  from 
(select t.type
from temp1 LATERAL VIEW posexplode(c1.array_of_struct_field1) dummy as alias1, t
union all
select t.type
from temp1 LATERAL VIEW posexplode(c1.array_of_struct_field2) dummy as alias1, t ) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one in your code
`set hive.stats.column.autogather=false;`